# if else condition doesn't seem to work correctly in PHP

Tags: php

I am stuck with a weird `if else` behavior and I really don't know what is causing that!

I am trying to calculate some value according to some conditions as below:

```
if ($totalWeight < 500 && $finalCurrency == "INR") {
  echo "45 INR";
} else if ($totalWeight > 500 && $finalCurrency == "INR") {
  echo "100 INR";
} else if ($totalWeight < 500 && $finalCurrency == "USD") {
  echo "4 USD";
} else {
  echo "Unable";
}
```

This condition is always jumping to `else` and is showing "Unable". I checked the `$totalWeight` and `$finalCurrency` variables by printing them and they are displayed just fine. If they are fine, then why is this condition always going to `else`?

Comment: do `var_dump($totalWeight,$finalCurrency);` and paste the output into your question.

Comment: Your $totalWeight isn't 500 is it?

Comment: You printed the variables, but haven't told **US** what their *values* and their *types* were. However, you can be sure of one thing - it's not `if else` not working correctly, and it's not a problem in PHP, it's 100% undoubtedly your mistake. *"If they are fine, then why is this condition always going to else?"* - well, they are not "fine" and that's the reason.

Comment: @JParkinson1991 nah they are basically below 500 in most of the cases

Comment: @N.B. the $totalWeight is a numeric value and $finalCurrency is string as you can see above in the code

Comment: the code is not wrong syntactically

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that you don't think of some case that may happen.

Here is your code :

```
if($totalWeight < 500 && $finalCurrency == "INR") {
    echo "45 INR";
} else if($totalWeight > 500 && $finalCurrency == "INR") {
    echo "100 INR";
} else if($totalWeight < 500 && $finalCurrency == "USD") {
    echo "4 USD";
} else {
    echo "Unable";
}
```

So what happen if :

- `$totalWeight = 500` -> you go to `else {}`
- `$finalCurrency` different that `INR` or `USD` -> you go to `else {}`

If you are in one on this case you will go to `else {}`

So add `if($totalWeight <= 500...)` OR `if($totalWeight >= 500...)` and you should be good for the first case at least.

Comment: the thing is, $totalWeight never actually goes above or even equal to 500, it stays around at 50-60 and $finalCurrency will always be INR or USD

Comment: Please show us the output of $totalWeight and $finalCurrency so we can understand the problem with the if / else :)

Answer (score 1):

Rearranging complex conditionals like this can be instructive. If we break things apart so that we check first currency, and then weight, and make sure we always have an `else` case, we get something like this:

```
if ($finalCurrency == "INR") {
  if ( $totalWeight < 500 ) { 
    echo "45 INR";
  }
  elseif ($totalWeight > 500) {
    echo "100 INR";
  }
  else {
    echo "Unable";
  }
} elseif ($finalCurrency == "USD") {
  if ( $totalWeight < 500 ) {
    echo "4 USD";
  }
  else {
    echo "Unable";
  }
} else {
  echo "Unable";
}
```

In this structure, there are actually three branches that lead to "Unable":

- If the currency is INR, and the weight is *exactly 500*
- If the currency is USD, and the weight is *more than or equal to 500*
- If the currency is anything other than INR and USD

The first one is the most likely to be a bug, and the second should probably be *more than* rather than *more than or equal to*.

That would leave us with this:

```
if ($finalCurrency == "INR") {
  if ( $totalWeight <= 500 ) { 
    echo "45 INR";
  }
  else {
    echo "100 INR";
  } 
} elseif ($finalCurrency == "USD") {
  if ( $totalWeight <= 500 ) {
    echo "4 USD";
  }
  else {
    echo "Unable";
  }
} else {
  echo "Unable";
}
```

Note that this structure gives us another advantage: we can echo a different message in each "Unable" case, to see where the code is going.

Comment: actually i tried this aswell and condition still jumped to else and that's where i decided to consider stackoverflow because it is becoming too weird

Comment: @Mann Then you should show us your *best* attempt, with *exactly* the input and output you've got. That is, a [mcve]. For instance, if you have code like my last example and it hits the last `else`, you can eliminate all reference to `$totalWeight`, because you know it's never being looked at.